# YII2 : two models form validation, 2nd model require depend on 1st model input

Tags: php, validation, yii2, gii

I am using YII2, advanced template, generate models using gii.

I have created a form with two models (**A** and **B**), all validation rules define in respective model except one rule, what is the best practice for the following case.

in form

input fields for model **A**.
two input fields and one radio button **CATEGORY** (**YES** or **NO**). all require

input fields for model **B**.
three input fields are require and

four extra input fields are depend on **CATEGORY** radio button, 
If user checked on **YES** than extra fields are require and if checked on **NO** than no need for extra fields.

so how can I define a rule for client and server side validation? in which model? one solution in my mind is create a hybrid model and define all rules with dependency

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for your query.

Comment: it sounds too complicated, please try to make it clear with examples.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I find this solution.

for example if your category attribute is in model A and if it was 'yes' then item attribute in model B should be required.

for this example:

model A.php:

```
class A extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $category;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['category'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }



}
```

B.php
class B extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord

```
{
    public $item;
    public $category;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['item'], 'safe'],
            [['item'], 'required', 'when' => function($model) {
                return $model->category == 'yes';
            }]
        ];
    }       
}
```

and in controller

```
$a = new A();
$b = new B();
if ($a->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $b->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $b->category= Yii::$app->request->post()['First']['category'];

            $isValid = $a->validate();
            $isValid = $b->validate() && $isValid;
            if ($isValid) {
                echo 'its valid';
            }


        }
```